# How to make a responsive div for position: absolute

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make responsive design for a website. Don't know how to do it for a div which I use it with `position: absolute;`

Here are my HTML and CSS:

```css
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}
#nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 176px;
  top: 34px;
}
#content {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 190px;
  top: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <a href="index.html">
    <img src="static/gfx/logo.png">
  </a>
</div>
<div id="nav"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</div>

<div id="content">asdsa</div>
```

I've tried everything but can't figured it out. `div` is fixed.

Comment: use a framework like bootstrap or sementaic UI.

Comment: Absolute positioning does not lend itself to responsive design. There are much better layout methods..see [**http://learnlayout.com/**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Tweak the `top` and `left` properties in their respective `@media` section

Comment: Dont reinvent the wheel.. Use frameworks like "Foundation" or "Bootstrap"

Answer (score -1):

Use a media query to set different offsets for each resolution:

```
@media (min-resolution: 144dpi) {
 #logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px; 
  top: 20px;
  }
}

@media (min-resolution: 96dpi) {
 #logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px; 
  top: 10px;
  }
}
```

As an alternative, relative units (`%`, `em`, etc) would be an option as well.

For a responsive `iframe`, use the following process:

> It's key to specify the container's `position` to be `relative`. This allows us to absolutely position the `iframe` within it, which is needed to make it responsive.
>
> The `padding-bottom` value is calculated based on the aspect ratio of your content. To find the aspect ratio of a container, use this formula: `height ÷ width = aspect ratio`
>
> `height` is set to `0` because `padding-bottom` gives the `iframe` it’s `height`.
>       Using `overflow: hidden` is important because it ensures if any content does protrude outside of the container, it will be hidden and avoid screwing up the sites layout.
>
> Like with most absolutely positioned elements, we need to set the `top` and `left` properties so the `iframe` gets put in the right place.
>
> Finally, `width` and `height` are set to `100%` so the `iframe` takes up `100%` of the container's space.

**References**

- [Pixel Density List](http://pixensity.com/list/)
- [Responsive iframes](https://benmarshall.me/responsive-iframes/)